# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MYSQLdb' in anaconda

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have been trying to install mysqlclient for hours now using a fresh anaconda environment in python 3.7.

I have looked up other post on stackoverflow.

when i try to import MYSQLdb in jupyter notebook:

```
import MYSQLdb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18060/1995325395.py in <module>
----> 1 import MYSQLdb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MYSQLdb'
```

what i have tired

```
pip install mysqlclient
pip3 install mysqlclient
conda install -c anaconda mysql-python
conda install -c anaconda mysqlclient
```

I also tried installing other packages like mysql connector and sqlalchemy, but all got stuck in import MYSQLdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import with error handling:

```
try:
    import MySQLdb
except ImportError:
    import pymysql

    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Eventually you need to also install `pymysql` to make it work like this.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are installing the package in different environment
check the kernel in jupyter and which env you are working on